# Vmware View 5.2 PCOIP flash performance with ZeroClient

Tags: flash, vmware-view, pcoip

At the moment i'm testing a VDI with VMware View 5.2 and LG CloudMonitor 23CAV42K.

My VMs Settings:

- Win7 Pro
- 1 virt. socket with 2 cores per socket (Xeon X5450)
- 2GB RAM
- Teradici Audio Drivers
- Linked Clone and installed with EMC + VMware performance guide

Pool Settings:

- 3D-Render: Softwaer 512MB
- 1 Display
- Flash Quality middle
- Flash Regulator disable

GPO:

- audio session bandwidth: 1600
- max link rate: 90000
- maximum frame rate: 30
- the rest is unconfigured

The CloudMonitor has the resolution 1680x1050 and wired with 100 MB/FD

The Problem:

e.g. Youtube videos works in large view with 720p with some sound interrupts but fullscreen looks like a flip-book. Are there some further settings that i have to set or are there some well-known settings for the minimum image quality and initial image quality?

my aim is getting 720p videos working in fullscreen. thanks

Comment: 100Mb LAN or WAN? Are there any WLANs involved? Are there any routers or firewalls in between zero client and connection server and/or vm? Have you verified layer 2 to see if there are any errors there?

Comment: sorry for my late answer. we are using 100 MB LAN. The only firewall is the windows firewall on connection server. PCOIP stats shows that 1200 of 1500 bandwidth is used. On layer 2 there a no errors.

Answer (score 0):

we use Teradici cards to offload the CPU as well as the audio.  Once you install the card, add the Teradici audio driver to your VM.

Your bandwith usage will go up however.  Without the Teradici driver, our audio bandwith was around 100-150kb/s.  With the driver, it went up to 450-500kb/s.  But I believe that you can modify the allowable amount in the pcoip policies.